# Tray icon  и закрытия окна

Tags: qt, c++

После закрытия окна приложения (нажатиям на |x|), приложения переходит в область уведомления, и, соответственно, если нажать на иконку в этой области, приложения открывается, в том состоянии, в котором было закрыто. Пример такого приложения UTorrent. Я смог огранизовать создания иконки с контекстным меню в этой области уведомления, но я понятия не имею, как организовать то, что описано выше.

Answer (score 1):

Пример:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-systray.html